# Django m2m relation of the model with itself with extra attributes

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I tried to create a model with a many to many self relation, i put this in my code:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shape_clm = models.ManyToManyField("self", through='Friend',                                                                symmetrical=False) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Friend(models.Model):
    pers_one = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    pers_two = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

But when i tried to migrate the model to the DB the following error is raised:

```
Friend.pers_one: reverse accessor for Friend.pers_one clashes with reverse accessor for Friend.pers_two
```

I'm using Postgres as DB server, how i can make this m2m relation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `related_name` keyword argument, otherwise the ORM can't tell how will you refer to either of the fields.

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    pers_one = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='pers_ones')
    pers_two = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='pers_twos')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `related_name` arguments to your `ForeignKey`s in the `Friend` ModelClass:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    pers_one = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="friends_one")
    pers_two = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="friends_two")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

For more information about `related_name` take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

Comment: I put a related_name to my fields, but the error continues. Finally, i add the field unique_together('pers_one', 'pers_two') to the class Meta inside the class Friend, and it work perfectly, thanks for the answer anyway